# Do Variadic Template Parameters Always Have to be Last?

Tags: c++, templates, parameters, variadic-templates

Do I always have to place variadic template parameters at the end of my template parameters?

```
template <size_t begin = 0U, typename... Tp>
void foo(tuple<Tp...> t);
```

For example I get all kinds of errors with this:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>
using namespace std;

template <typename... Tp, size_t begin = 0U>
enable_if_t<begin == sizeof...(Tp), void> foo(tuple<Tp...>& t){
    cout << endl;
}

template <typename... Tp, size_t begin = 0U>
enable_if_t<begin < sizeof...(Tp), void> foo(tuple<Tp...>& t) {
    cout << get<begin>(t) << ' ';
    foo<Tp..., begin + 1>(t);
}

int main() {
    tuple<int, string, float> t = make_tuple(42, "Jonathan Mee", 13.13);

    foo(t);
}
```

When [run on gcc 5.1](http://ideone.com/Py0hW7) gives me:

> prog.cpp: In instantiation of `std::enable_if_t<(begin < sizeof... (Tp)), void> foo(std::tuple<_Elements ...>&) [with Tp = {int, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, float}; unsigned int begin = 0u; std::enable_if_t<(begin < sizeof... (Tp)), void> = void]`:
>   prog.cpp:21:7:   required from here
>   prog.cpp:15:23: error: no matching function for call to `foo(std::tuple<int, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, float>&)`
>   `foo<Tp..., begin + 1>(t);`
>   
>   prog.cpp:8:43: note: candidate: `template<class ... Tp, unsigned int begin> std::enable_if_t<(begin == sizeof... (Tp)), void> foo(std::tuple<_Elements ...>&)`
>   `enable_if_t<begin == sizeof...(Tp), void> foo(tuple<Tp...>& t){`
>   
>   prog.cpp:8:43: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
>   prog.cpp:13:42: note: candidate: `template<class ... Tp, unsigned int begin> std::enable_if_t<(begin < sizeof... (Tp)), void> foo(std::tuple<_Elements ...>&)`
>   `enable_if_t<begin < sizeof...(Tp), void> foo(tuple<Tp...>& t) {`
>   
>   prog.cpp:13:42: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:

When the arguments are swapped to:

```
template <size_t begin = 0U, typename... Tp>
void foo(tuple<Tp...> t);
```

The program runs correctly: http://ideone.com/SozUbb

If this is really a requirement that variadic template parameters be last can someone give me a source on this information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variardic arguments don't have to be last -- but it doesn't help you.

Your error is in the recursive call, when you try to set `begin` to be something different than `0`.  In that line, the compiler cannot figure out that your `begin` is supposed to be the `std::size_t` parameter, and bails out.

This compiles fine even in gcc 5.1:

```
template <class... Tp, std::size_t begin = 0U>
auto foo(std::tuple<Tp...>& t) -> std::enable_if_t<begin == sizeof...(Tp), void> {
  std::cout << '\n';
}

template <class... Tp, std::size_t begin = 0U>
auto foo(std::tuple<Tp...>& t) -> std::enable_if_t<begin < sizeof...(Tp), void> {
  std::cout << '\n';
}
```

(I rewrote it to figure out where it was going wrong, so it is slightly different in unimportant ways).

The important way it differs it the lack of recursive call.

As an aside, your printing code is a bit awkward.  Consider using something like `for_each_arg`:

```
template<class F, class...Args>
void for_each_arg(F&& f, Args&&...args) {
  using discard=int[];
  (void)discard{((
    f(std::forward<Args>(args))
  ),void(),0)...,0};
}
```

either mix the above with `std::apply` or write your own:

```
namespace details {
  template<class F, class Tuple, std::size_t...Is>
  decltype(auto) apply( std::index_sequence<Is...>, F&& f, Tuple&& args )
  {
    return std::forward<F>(f)( std::get<Is>(std::forward<Tuple>(args))... );
  }
}
template<class F, class Tuple>
decltype(auto) apply(F&& f, Tuple&& tuple) {
  using dTuple = std::decay_t<Tuple>;
  return details::apply(
    std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<dTuple>::value>{},
    std::forward<F>(f),
    std::forward<Tuple>(tuple)
  );
}

template<class F, class Tuple>
decltype(auto) for_each_tuple_element( F&& f, Tuple&& tuple ) {
  return apply(
    [&](auto&&...args){
      for_each_arg( std::forward<F>(f), decltype(args)(args)... );
    },
    std::forward<Tuple>(tuple)
  );
}
```

and now you don't have a recursion depth equal to the number of elements in your tuple.

```
template <class Tuple>
void foo(Tuple&& tuple) {
  for_each_tuple_element(
    [](auto&& arg){ std::cout << decltype(arg)(arg); },
    std::forward<Tuple>(tuple)
  );
  std::cout << '\n';
}
```

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d9a29289470742cc).

Comment: I'm having trouble following what you're doing in `for_each_arg`. Can you explain that?

Comment: @JonathanMee I create an array of integers, all zero.  While doing so, I pack-expand an expression that invokes `f` on each index `Is` of the `Tuple` `args`.   [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28263000/correct-usage-of-for-each-arg-too-much-forwarding) is a discussion of a similar `for_each_arg` that uses `std::initalizier_list` instead of an array.

Comment: 2 questions after having read through your links. 1) Why cast your `int[]` to `void` 2) in the `int[]`'s intialization, how does the compiler know to repeat all of `((f(forward<Args>(args))), void(), 0)`?

Comment: @jon `(void)` can dismiss some warnings on some compilers (unused temporary or somesuch).  The `...` does the pack expand on the previous expression, in `()` in this case.  Note the awkwardly placed `((` and `)` and `)`: written that way to highlight the non-boilerplate-line of the technique.

Comment: OK, so we're creating an `int[]` which will never be used in order to call `f` `sizeof...(Args)` times. Fine, then why the two comma operators in the repeated parenthesis, wouldn't we just need `, 0` not `, void(), 0`? And why do we add one more 0 to the array than there are elements in `args`?

Comment: @JonathanMee 1) defend against overloaded comma operators and 2) handle the case where we have an empty pack by ensuring that the array has at least one element.

Comment: @T.C. aka: 1) to defend against evil, 2) do defend against nothing.

Comment: @JonathanMee So, the thing is, in generic code, you gotta be conservative and deal with edge cases.  You have to examine every expression and think "what are the possible overloads?".  You have to deal with empty parameter packs, and million-sized parameter packs.  The possibility that the return value of `f` on the argument returns a type with an overloaded comma operator is handled by doing a `f(blah), void()` -- you cannot overload with `void()`.  The trailing zero deals with the fact that zero-sized arrays are illegal, and an empty pack would otherwise attempt to create a zero-sized array.

Comment: @Yakk Yikes, right when I finally understood this you changed, `invoke` for `forward`. How does that work?

Comment: @JonathanMee Can you be more specific?  :)  `for_each_tuple_element` takes a function and a tuple, and invokes the function on each element.  `apply` is an implementation of `std::apply`, which takes a function and a tuple, and invokes the function with the contents of the tuple.  `for_each_arg` takes a function and a pack of arguments, and invokes the function on each argument.  So `for_each_tuple_element(f,tup)` is `apply(for_each_arg(f,...), tup)`?

Comment: @Yakk I mean I think I get what you're saying, but why couldn't I just do: `experimental::apply([](auto& i) { cout << i; }, make_tuple(3.14, "Hello World!", -1));`

Comment: @JonathanMee `apply( f, make_tuple(3.14, "Hello World!", -1))`  calls `f(3.14, "Hello World!", -1)`

Comment: @Yakk And it finally clicks. Thank you.

Comment: @Yakk A couple more questions about `for_each_arg`: 1) Why does the compiler require us to do the `using discard = int[]` statement? 2) Why are you `forward`ing the values passed to `f`? I have a more in depth question on this as well, but I've posted that here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/35893826/2642059

Comment: @JonathanMee 1) It doesn't?  It makes it clear we are discarding this value.  2) Why wouldn't I forward arguments?  I see no reason to discard l/r valueness of the argument references.

Comment: @Yakk So when I try doing: `template<class F, class...Args> void for_each_arg(F&& f, Args&&...args) {static_cast<void>(int[]{((f(std::forward<Args>(args))), void(), 0)..., 0});}` I get the error: "expected primary-expression before `int`: `static_cast<void>(int[]{((f(std::forward<Args>(args))), void(), 0)..., 0});`": http://ideone.com/QktBcc

Answer (score 7):

The problem isn't the template declaration. This is perfectly fine:

```
template <typename... Tp, size_t begin = 0U>
void foo(tuple<Tp...> t);
```

The problem is this call:

```
foo<Tp..., begin + 1>(t);
```

While you *can* provide a defaulted template argument after a parameter pack, you have no way of actually setting it later. The compiler has no way of knowing where the pack ends and the argument after the pack begins.

You should flip the ordering to put `begin` as the first argument, defaulted:

```
template <size_t begin = 0U, typename... Tp>
void foo(tuple<Tp...> t);
```

so that your recursive call can be:

```
foo<begin + 1>(t);
```

Comment: How can you say this is fine? If I leave everything defaulted [gcc 5.1 gives me an error](http://ideone.com/Py0hW7).

Comment: Yeah? if that declaration is "perfectly fine" why can't I call: `foo(t)`?

Comment: @JonathanMee You can't call `foo(t)` for reasons that I explain in the answer: the recursive call is ill-formed.

Comment: Ah, got it. Though I'd debate the "no way of knowing" statement, it's always the last argument.

Comment: @JonathanMee Parameter packs provided as arguments have to be last - it is what it is.

Answer (score 1):

According to the standard *§14.1/11 Template parameters [temp.param]:*

> *If a template-parameter of a primary class template or alias template is a template parameter pack, it shall be the last template-parameter. A template parameter pack of a function template shall not be followed by another template parameter unless that template parameter can be deduced from the parameter-type-list
>   of the function template or has a default argument.*

Thus your setting is correct since variadic argument is followed by a default template argument. However, you have a syntax error, you should change to:

```
template <typename... Tp, size_t begin = 0U>
                  ^^^^^^
void foo(tuple<Tp...> t);
```

That is, in the template argument list `...` must preceed `Tp`.

Comment: It says an: "A template parameter pack of a function template shall not be followed by another template parameter unless that template parameter can be deduced from the parameter-type-list of the function template or has a default argument." Isn't that saying that defaulted template parameters like mine should be able to follow a varadic template parameter?

Comment: This is true, but isn't the issue.